# Find replacing dictionaries in regex

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, search, regex-group

Okay, so I have the following piece of code.

```
out = out + re.sub('\{\{([A-z]+)\}\}', values[re.search('\{\{([A-z]+)\}\}',item).group().strip('{}')],item) + " "
```

Or, more broken down:

```
out = out + re.sub(
    '\{\{([A-z]+)\}\}', 
    values[
        re.search(
            '\{\{([A-z]+)\}\}',
            item
        ).group().strip('{}')
    ],
    item
) + " "
```

So, basically, if you give it a string which contains {{reference}}, it will find instances of that, and replace them with the given reference. The issue with it in it's current form is that it can only work based on the first reference. For example, say my values dictionary was

```
values = {
    'bob': 'steve',
    'foo': 'bar'
}
```

and we passed it the string

```
item = 'this is a test string for {{bob}}, made using {{foo}}'
```

I want it to put into `out`

```
'this is a test string for steve, made using bar'
```

but what it currently outputs is

```
 'this is a test string for steve, made using steve'
```

How can I change the code such that it takes into account the position in the loop.

It should be noted, that doing a word split would not work, as the code needs to work even if the input is `{{foo}}{{steve}}`

Comment: Be aware that `[A-z]` is not only apha, it includes every character that are between `Z` and `a`, ie. `[\]^_` and \`

Comment: This is fine, it's only me using the code and I don't intend to use any of those symbols. I might change it to `[A-Za-z]` anyway though, thanks for the heads up

Comment: Is it possible to use different the format of reference `{{reference}}`? Because if  you could change it to {reference}, then you could just : `'this is a test string for {bob}, made using {foo}'.format(**values)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the output using the following code,

```
replace_dict = { 'bob': 'steve','foo': 'bar'}
item = 'this is a test string for {{foo}}, made using {{steve}}'
replace_lst = re.findall('\{\{([A-z]+)\}\}', item)
out = ''
for r in replace_lst:
    if r in replace_dict:
        item = item.replace('{{' + r + '}}', replace_dict[r])
print item
```

Comment: this leaves {{ }} on either side of the string, I want those stripped out. Can you add this please?

Comment: figured it out: `item = item.replace("{{"+r+"}}", values[r])`

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
import re

values = {
    'bob': 'steve',
    'foo': 'bar'
}

item = 'this is a test string for {{bob}}, made using {{foo}}'

pat = re.compile(r'\{\{(.*?)\}\}')

fields = pat.split(item)
fields[1] = values[fields[1]]
fields[3] = values[fields[3]]
print ''.join(fields)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could change the format of reference from `{{reference}}` to `{reference}`, you could achieve your needs just with format method (instead of using regex):

```
values = {
'bob': 'steve',
'foo': 'bar'
}
item = 'this is a test string for {bob}, made using {foo}'
print(item.format(**values))
# prints: this is a test string for steve, made using bar
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `re.search` will start looking from the beginning of the string each time you call it, thus always returning the first match `{{bob}}`.

You can access the match object you are currently replacing by [passing a function as replacement to `re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
values = { 'bob': 'steve','foo': 'bar'}
item = 'this is a test string for {{bob}}, made using {{foo}}'
pattern = r'{{([A-Za-z]+)}}'
# replacement function
def get_value(match):
    return values[match.group(1)]
result =  re.sub(pattern, get_value, item)
# print result => 'this is a test string for steve, made using bar'
```